# Get current t-sql procedure name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have several t-sql procedures with name like Test;1, Test;2, Test;3 etc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] ; 1
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)

  SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] ; 2
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)

  SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
GO
```

Is that any way to get full procedure name with it version?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve that information from [sys.numbered_procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-numbered-procedures-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You can filter based on the object_id and it returns the procedure number. To get the procedure name, you use the same functions you're already using. That also returns the T-SQL code if you want it.

You'll also want to use [sys.numbered_procedures_parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-numbered-procedure-parameters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in order to get the information about parameters for these types of procedures. This is necessary since they can also have different parameters.

By the way, numbered procedures is deprecated functionality. As such, it's not recommended for use. Further, it won't work with newer functionality such as CREATE OR ALTER statements. I would strongly caution against using numbered procedures.